# Core Plot - dynamic line graph - line drawing always starts from (0,0)

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, linegraph

I'm using the following: Core Plot 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1, iOS 8.3, and Objective-C.

I'm currently able to take incoming voltage data from my Cypress BLE module, and store points of data in an `NSMutableArray *voltageData`. I use those points as values on my y-axis in the delegate method `numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`.  I have an `NSTimer` object that triggers a call to a method that captures the voltage data every 0.1 ms.  Here is that method:

```
// kMaxDataPoints = 50;
// '_real' is the voltage data of type Float32

- (void)incomingData:(nonnull NSTimer *)theTimer {

    if (self.plotData.count >= kMaxDataPoints) {
        [self.plotData removeAllObjects];
        [self.plot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, kMaxDataPoints)];
        [self.voltageData removeAllObjects];
        self.currentIndex = -1;
    }

    self.currentIndex++;
    if (self.voltageData == nil) {
        self.voltageData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [self.voltageData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_real]];
    [self.plotData addObject:@(_real)];
    [self.plot insertDataAtIndex:(self.plotData.count - 1) numberOfRecords:1];
}
```

My mutable arrays `voltageData` and `plotData` always have the correct values.  Every time the graph reaches the end of the data points, it "restarts" at the correct voltage value but the data line is "attached" to another straight line coming from the origin (0,0).  Imagine this straight line drawing out the data line...that's what it looks like.

And ideas as to what is happening?  Just as a side note, I am not replacing any point with another point.  I'm remove all points from the arrays, and clearing out the whole plot, before restarting again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `-reloadData` on the plot instead of `-deleteDataInIndexRange:`. This makes sure that all of the old plot data is removed.

Comment: That fixed the "drawing of the line from (0,0) origin" scenario, but unfortunately now (having replaced `-deletDataInIndexRange:` with `-reloadData` on `self.plot`), where ever my last point was before the max points has been reached, a straight line follows the data line as it moves from left to right (as data accumulates).  So imagine, the data line is doing it's thing, but it looks like a straight line is pulling it across the graph.  I don't know if this is supposed to happen, but I wanted the graph (the line, rather) refresh so that every time the line reaches the end, a new one is made

Comment: Have the `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` method return `self.plotData.count`. It sounds like you're telling the plot that it has more points available than you really do.

Comment: The `plotData` and `voltageData` arrays hold the same data. Is there any reason you need two copies of everything?

Comment: Good call on the two arrays issue...that wasn't the problem but it was unnecessary.  However, switching `kMaxDataPoints` with `self.plotData.count` did the trick!  I keep forgetting that `-numberOfRecordsForPlot` gets called as often as `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`, so every time it did, it would always include the entire length of my data set (instead of solely the data I actually have to display.)  Thanks again